# format string and get data

Tags: java, string-formatting

I had a string as

```
Action Completed-PPN-P1:1234
```

How can I format to get the words separately to check the condition as

```
if(string == Action Completed)
if(string == PPN)
if......
```

How can I format to get above code?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want? To spilt on "-"?

Comment: is it a `and` join? ex if (string == Action Completed and string == PPN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `String.split` method which takes a regex pattern, depending on what you want you need to change the pattern - but to split the string on "-" and ":" you do do this

```
final String myString = "Action Completed-PPN-P1:1234";

final String[] myStringArr = myString.split("-|:");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myStringArr));
```

Output:

```
[Action Completed, PPN, P1, 1234]
```

Answer (score 1):

use .contains  method if you want to see if string contains certain characters.For this ,

```
if(string.contains("Action Completed"))
if(string.contains("PPN"))
if......
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String[] split = "Action Completed-PPN-P1:1234".split("[-:]");
if("Action Completed".equals(split[0])){
if("PPN".equals(split[1])){ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the basic library functions:

```
String entry = "Action Completed-PPN-P1:1234";
String[] splits = entry.split("-");
```

Which will give you and array of all this:

```
splits[0] -- "Action Completed"
splits[1] -- "PPN"
splits[2] -- "P1:1234"
```